# Endless redirect when gad and gclid are added to the url?

Tags: magento-1.9, redirect

**Magento 1.9**

As soon as those 2 Google parameters are added to any product URL of my shop, I am getting the "this website does not redirect properly" error. I tried disabling all caches and also checked the htaccess, nothing here seems to be the problem.

**Example:**
https://www.example.com/this.htm?gad=1&gclid=Cj0KCQjwzdOlBhCNARIsAPMwjbwp95MujqC-2YMvDe8pVnvF5WzcHfU74FmpGLK_GZdRQ-h-ZCJHJPoaAomeEALw_wcB --> redirect error

https://www.example.com/this.htm --> works just fine

Any ideas?